# Generating URL for YQL

Tags: java, android, json, yql

I am working on a java project in which I need to generate url to get data i.e open,low,high,close etc prices from yahoo

Similar post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17494758/how-to-implement-yql-in-java) suggests to use  URLEncoder.encode(query, "UTF-8") from java.net.URLEncoder but this generates url in a differnt format.

Example:
For this query

> select * from yahoo.finance.historicaldata where symbol in
>   ("YHOO","AAPL") and startDate = "2014-01-01" and endDate =
>   "2014-02-01"

It gives url:

> http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select+*+from+yahoo.finance.historicaldata+where+symbol+in+%28%22YHOO%22%2C%22AAPL%22%29+and+startDate+%3D+%222014-01-01%22+and+endDate+%3D+%222014-02-01%22&format=json

whereas I need url in this format

> https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20yahoo.finance.historicaldata%20where%20symbol%20in%20(%22YHOO%22%2C%22AAPL%22)%20and%20startDate%20%3D%20%222014-01-01%22%20and%20endDate%20%3D%20%222014-02-01%22&format=json&diagnostics=true&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys&callback=

Please suggest how I convert this query to above mentioned url.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

This question is answered here [Java equivalent to JavaScript's encodeURIComponent that produces identical output?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/607176/java-equivalent-to-javascripts-encodeuricomponent-that-produces-identical-outpu).

The solution offers the source code to the `EncodingUtil` class.  You can use that class like this (for your specific example):

```
String query = "select * from yahoo.finance.historicaldata where symbol in (\"YHOO\",\"AAPL\") and startDate = \"2014-01-01\" and endDate = \"2014-02-01\"";

System.out.println("https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q="+EncodingUtil.encodeURIComponent(query)+"&format=json&diagnostics=true&env="+EncodingUtil.encodeURIComponent("store://datatables.org/alltableswithkeys")+"&callback=");
```

And unrelated to your quesiton, be careful using `select *`.  If Yahoo adds or removes a field, your code that handles the returned JSON object may break.